# Custom DependencyProperty with custom datatype

Tags: wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I want to create a custom DependencyProperty for a usercontrol

```
 public Table Grids
    {
        get { return (Table)GetValue(GridsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GridsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Grids.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty GridsProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Grids", typeof(Table), 
                typeof(MyViewer), new UIPropertyMetadata(10));
```

Here Table is a custom datatype used to store rows & Columns. That will help me in using them like;

```
<my:MyViewer 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="66,54,0,0" 
    x:Name="MyViewer1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Height="400" 
    Width="400"
    Grids="10"/>
```

or

```
<my:MyViewer 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="66,54,0,0" 
    x:Name="MyViewer1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Height="400" 
    Width="400"
    Grids="10,20"/>
```

I tried to define the Table datatype as;

```
public class Table 
    {
        public int Rows { get; set; }
        public int Columns { get; set; }

        public Table(int uniform)
        {
            Rows = uniform;
            Columns = uniform;
        }

        public Table(int rows, int columns)
        {
            Rows = rows;
            Columns = columns;
        }
    }
```

but it's not working; when i use Grids="10" in XAML it breaks.
Can anybody help me to achive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value in the property metadata is of the wrong type. This will result in an exception when the MyViewer class is loaded. Set the default value to e.g. `new Table(10)`.

Besides that, XAML/WPF will not automatically convert the strings `"10"` or `"10,20"` to instances of your Table class by calling the right constructors. You will have to write a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx) to perform this conversion.

A simple TypeConverter could look like this:

```
public class TableConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        string tableString = value as string;
        if (tableString == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }

        string[] numbers = tableString.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 2);
        int rows = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
        int columns = rows;

        if (numbers.Length > 1)
        {
            columns = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
        }

        return new Table { Rows = rows, Columns = columns };
    }
}
```

The TypeConverter would be associated with your Table class like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(TableConverter))]
public class Table
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't the default value you are setting in the registration method a data type mismatch? I believe you want the first `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` parameter to be something like:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new Table())
```

or

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null)
```

Then in XAML you could do the following:

```
<my:MyViewer>
    <my:MyViewer.Grids>
        <Table Rows="10" Column="20"/>
    </my:MyViewer.Grids>
</my:MyViewer>
```

Comment: Then in XAML you coule do the following:

<my:MyViewer>
    <my:MyViewer.Grids>
        <Table Rows="10" Column="20"/>
    <my:MyViewer.Grids>
</my:MyViewer>

Comment: Thanks!! I'm able to achieve the result with this way. However @Clemens solution is more inducive and simple.
<my:MyViewer 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="66,54,0,0" 
    x:Name="MyViewer1" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Height="400" 
    Width="400"
    Grids="10,20"/>